# Print Multiple Selections in Excel into 1 Single page PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am a newbie to Excel VBA, and I get this code from https://trumpexcel.com/convert-excel-to-pdf/ to print selection into PDF.

My only concern at the moment is, how to make all of my uncontinuous selections printed into 1 single PDF. If anybody can help, I would be very grateful for that.

For example, in the photo below, you can see that if I select from the first row to the last row, then when I print Selection into PDF, it will be converted into 1 single page. But for example, I only want to print the Product 1 and Product 3 (skipping product 2), then I will only be able to print them into 2 separated pages. How can I make this into 1 page is my question.
Code:

```
Sub PrintSelectionToPDF()
    Dim ThisRng As Range
    Dim strfile As String
    Dim myfile As Variant

    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
    Else
        Set ThisRng = Selection
    End If

    'Prompt for save location
    strfile = "Selection" & "_" _
        & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss") _
        & ".pdf"
    strfile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strfile
    myfile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
        (InitialFileName:=strfile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and File Name to Save as PDF")
    If myfile <> "False" Then 'save as PDF
        ThisRng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            myfile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Else
        MsgBox "No File Selected. PDF will not be saved", vbOKOnly, "No File Selected"
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: thank you you guys for pointing out, I did upload the picture for example and also the code up there.

Comment: Well, I guess that is just how the `ExportAsFixedFormat` handles multiple selections (each area starts a new page). Two possibilities to get it on one page: ① Hide all rows that you don't want to export (or filter). Then export and afterwards make them visible again. ② Copy the rows you want to export to a new (temporary) worksheet, export that worksheet and delete it afterwards. • Decide yourself which one would be more practicable for you. I think the first method will be more reliable and possible less errors can occur while the second one is probably easier to code (just my opinion).